# name 'Start()' not defined

Tags: python-2.7

I have two files in a game I am currently making (not finished). They are the same directory. When I run either of the two files, the terminal in macos Serria is giving me this error (and yes, I did research, to no avail). BTW, thank you, StackOverFlow, for answering (and downvoting when needed) questions. It truly helped me.:

```
File "story.py", line 3, in <module>
    from engine import *
File "SurvivalAdventureGame/Resources/engine.py", line 2, in <module>
    from story import *
File "SurvivalAdventureGame/Resources/story.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Start(Scene):
NameError: name 'Scene' is not defined
```

Here is story.py:

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint
from engine import *

class Start(Scene):
    print """
    You are flying to Brussels from Seattle. You *are* glad you received the bonus from work, you think to yourself.
    \nUnfortunally, you were only able to put 100$ towards the vacation due to your bastard landlord.
    \nYou muttered to yourself, "If this plane got League Pass, though. Warriors-Raptors would be lit."
    \nYep, your 14-year old son says as he reads The New Jim Crow. Your 9-year old son is playing Minecraft.
    \nThen the speakers boomed, as the crew said, "Hi. My name is Messlia and our pilot is temporarily incapacitated."
    \nA strange mixture of curses, crying, yells of terror, and silence filled the cabin.
    \n"We will land shortly on a grass clearing near trees."
    \nMore panic.
    \nYou cried as You told your panicking sons (and secretly myself) to do
    """
    print "1. Bring only a blanket, some food and water, some clothing, and every medication needed."
    print "2. Bring nothing"
    print "3. Bring everything you possibly can."

    action = raw_input("> ")

    if action == "1":
        print "You survived, crawling out the door with a painful leg injury."
        print "\n Your older son, a safety-first guy, escaped without ANY injury AT ALL. Your other son, however, has a gaping hole in his wrists."
        print "\n He sheds tears, clearly in pain, as you ponder your options."
        print "1. Splash with water and cover it with a blanket"
        print "2. Cover it with a towel."
        print "3. Splash it with water only."

        next = raw_input("> ")

        if next == "1":
            print "Your now have about 50 mL of water left. However, he has calmed down."
            Day1()

        elif next == "2":
            print "You now have to tend to the boy at all times. However, at least he will not get sick, right?"
            Day1()

        elif next == "3":
            print "You now only have 50 mL of water left. At least he calmed down a bit!"
            Day1()

        else:
            Stupid()

    elif actions =="2":
        print "You survive with no injuries, however, you have nothing and your youngest son just suffered a major wrist injury."
        Day1()

    elif next == "3":
        print "You, your sons, and 12 people die because of you delaying everyone else."
        Death()

    else:
        Stupid()

class Death(Scene):
    print "Either you, one or both of your sons or others died. You suck."

class Stupid(Scene):
    print "ERROR: OVERWHELMING STUPIDITY."
    print "You should enter the numbers without the period, without the words"
```

Here is engine.py:

```
from sys import exit
from story import *

class Scene(object):
    def __init__(self):
        start()
    def start(self):
        print "DOESNOTEXIST!"
        exit(1)

class Engine(object):
    def __init__(self, scene_map):
        self.scene_map = scene_map

    def play(self):
        current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
        while True:
            print "\n--------"
            next_scene_name = current_scene.start()
            current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

class Map(object):
    # Won't work now, Gotta finish writing the story!
    scenes = {
    "Start": Start(),
    "Day1": Day1(),
    "Day2": Day2(),
    "Day3": Day3(),
    "Day4": Day4(),
    "Day5": Day5(),
    "Day6": Day6(),
    "Day7": Day7(),
    "Day8": Day8(),
    "Death": Death(),
    "Stupid": Stupid(),
    }


    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene()


    def next_scene(self, scene_name):
        return Map.scenes.get(scene_name)


    def opening_scene(self):
        return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)

class play(object, Map):
    def __init__(self, map):
        the_map = Map('Start')
        the_map = Engine(the_map)
        a_game.play()
```

Comment: Python does not support recursive imports like this. Before you define `Scene`, you have `from story import *`, and it fails to do that because something depends on `Scene`, which isn't defined yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a circular dependency: in story you import * (everything) from engine and vice versa. This is not supported in Python.

Comment: @AbdiDhago you're not looking for an alternative to `import *` you're looking for a design change that removes the need for a circular dependency. A solution would be to extract the common logic into a 3rd file and use it (import * from it)  both in engine and story.